# Create Dict within list of dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dict within a list of dicts. How do I build the data structure and later to fetch the data via jinja2? 
Here is an example:

```
var = {
    'site': '', 
    'listofiles': [
        {'time': '', 'name': ''}
    ]
}

exampledata = {
    'site': 'DC1', 
    'listofiles': [
        {'time': 'Thu Oct 3 22:26:40 2019', 'name': 'file1'}, 
        {'time': 'Thu Oct 3 20:26:40 2019', 'name': 'file2'}, 
        {'time': 'Thu Oct 3 21:26:40 2019', 'name': 'file3'}
    ]
}
```

How to populate data within the var?
I have tried doing the following, but it will only give me
`{ 'DC1': [file1,file2,file3], 'DC2': [file1,file2] }`

```
exampledata = {}
for f in os.listdir(path):
   exampledata.setdefault(f.split('.')[1],[]).append(f)
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: how to populate the data in the exampledata format

Comment: Is still not clear, where does the data comes from?

Comment: What is `site`? What is `DC1`, `DC2`?

Comment: yes, `site` will be the key and `DC1` values

Comment: @DanielMesejo data is pull from the directory, which have list of files.

Comment: like to add the timestamps for each of the files last created/modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note! don't use 'path' name in your code for variable or anything as is the name of a builin module of python

use the following code. make_var function take 2 variables, the first variable is the site's name and the second variable is the directory's path which contains all the files you need to register for it. code is for Python3 only

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from pathlib import Path


def make_var(site_name, pth): 
    exampledata = {'site':site_name, 'listofiles':[]}
    p = Path(pth)
    for f in p.iterdir():
        if f.is_file():
            name = f.name.replace(f.suffix, '')
            tm = dt.utcnow().strftime('%a %b %H:%M:%S %Y')
            exampledata['listofiles'].append({'time':tm, 'name':name}) 
    return exampledata
```

Comment: thanks, I will check it out. The site is derive from the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by 'site' ...

The code below uses site as location on the file system. 
It iterates over the sites list and read the files for each site.

```
import os
import datetime

data = dict()

sites = ['.']
for site in sites:
    data['listofiles'] = []
    data['site'] = site
    for f in os.listdir(site):
        data['listofiles'].append(
            {'time': str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(site, f)))), 'name': f})
```

Comment: thanks, I will make some adjustment and but the site name is derive from the file